# Heredoc within command substitution: error when quotes or parentheses are unbalanced (bash and zsh)

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

Consider the following obfuscated script intended for printing a single quote, which works on `ksh`:

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo "$(cat <<EOF
'
EOF
)"
```

Output:

```
'
```

However, when I run the same script with `bash 3.2.51(1)` on OS X,

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "$(cat <<EOF
'
EOF
)"
```

bash reports the following errors:

```
./heredoc-within-cmdsubst: line 3: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
./heredoc-within-cmdsubst: line 6: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

And run with `zsh 5.0.2`,

```
#!/bin/zsh
echo "$(cat <<EOF
'
EOF
)"
```

zsh reports the following error:

```
./heredoc-within-cmdsubst:6: unmatched "
```

Similar errors occur when the single quote is replaced by a double quote or parenthesis. If I balance the single quote/double quote/parenthesis with a matching single quote/double quote/parenthesis, then the script runs fine with both bash and zsh.

Is this issue just a bug in (the relevant versions of) bash and zsh, or are there any syntactic rules violated here?

Answer (score 1):

I would consider this a parsing bug until/unless the developers say otherwise. The code works in `dash` as-is, and there is a similar unclosed-quote error in [this `zsh` question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25778521/1126841).

UPDATE: This is actually fixed in `bash` 4.1; I only checked in `zsh` 5.0.2 (the latest version is 5.0.6).

Comment: Too bad there are parsing bugs in such well-established shells. :(