# Bash/Osascript Error: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'

Tags: bash, applescript, osascript

I'm splitting a string using osascript (was working this way, not with bash), and assigning the resulting array to a bash variable, and continuing  with my bash script. I'm doing it like so:

```
tempArrayApplications=$(osascript >/dev/null <<EOF
    set oldDelimiters to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "/"
    set theArray to every text item of "$noSplitString"
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to oldDelimiters
    return theArray
EOF)
```

However, the command line returns the error that it went to the end of the file without finding the matching ')'. However, when I don't assign a bash variable to the osascript output, everything works fine, so I know it's not a problem with the AppleScript section. I ran shellcheck, and it doesn't detect any errors, and the other solutions seem to be related to an unclosed quote or unescaped character, but I don't seem to have that problem. Clearly it's due to trying to assign it to a bash variable, but for the life of me I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You have to put the closing `)` on a separate line, or the `EOF` marker is not recognized.

Comment: Almost a duplicate (was with whitespace after the `EOF` marker): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18660798/here-document-gives-unexpected-end-of-file-error

Comment: Also, shellcheck tells me "Add a linefeed between end token and terminating ')'.": https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1119

Comment: Tried putting it on a separate line, same error @BenjaminW.

Comment: Do you have trailing blanks after `EOF`?

Comment: No trailing blanks, my text editor (Sublime Text) catches that. @BenjaminW.

Comment: Then I don't know. Putting the `)` on a separate line makes the whole thing work for me, in both bash and sh. Do you insert carriage returns at line ends?

Comment: Huh, that's weird it works for me but not for you. And no, I don't insert carraige returns at line ends. @BenjaminW.

Comment: Wait, doesn't it work for me but not for you?

Comment: How exactly do you run this? Is it in a script?

Comment: Sorry bad wording, works for you, not for me. And yes this is in a script. @BenjaminW.

Comment: And how do you run it? What's in the shebang line?

Comment: The shebang is #!/bin/bash. I run it in terminal just by dragging the executable file path to the command line.

Comment: Oh, I get an error when using Bash 3.2 instead of Bash 4.4. Is the error you get when moving the parens to a separate line this one? `unexpected EOF while looking for matching \`''`

Comment: That would be this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25891644/heredoc-within-command-substitution-error-when-quotes-or-parentheses-are-unbala

Comment: And a solution to it would be to get a more recent Bash from, for example, Homebrew (https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/bash).

Comment: Yeah the error is what i stated in the title of the question, very similar to what you got. I'll update my bash and report back if that works.

Comment: But when you put the `)` on a separate line, does it still complain about "looking for matching `)`", or is it about "matching `'`"?

Comment: Looking for matching `)`, doesn't like that. @BenjaminW.

Comment: Then I definitely don't know, I'm afraid.

Comment: UPDATE: Just upgraded bash, no longer get the error! However, the array isn't being passed to the bash variable. I log theArray and i see everything, but when I log tempArrayApplications it's empty

Comment: You're not creating an array anyway, just a string. To read multiple lines into an array, have a look at `readarray`/`mapfile` (Bash 4.0 or newer).

Comment: Well, and it's empty because you throw away your output with `> /dev/null`.

Comment: Appears you're right. Got rid of the `/dev/null` statement and I can see the "array", but you're right, it's not really an array. I'll take a look at `readarray/mapfile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you paused to consider that you're taking a bash variable (`$noSplitString`); inserting this into an AppleScript that splits the text using `/` as the delimiter; executing this AppleScript inside a bash command (`osascript`); then storing its output (which actually gets destroyed) in another bash variable (`$tempArrayApplications`)...?

My inclination would be to remove the AppleScript altogether (3 out of its 5 lines are redundant, anyway), and create the array from the string within bash.

So, given this:

```
noSplitString="item 1/item 2/item 3"
```

Then simply do this:

```
IFS='/'
tempArrayApplications=($noSplitString)
```

Now `$tempArrayApplications` will be an array with three items, starting at index 0 and ending at index 2.  You can `echo` a specific element in the array like this:

```
echo "${tempArrayApplications[1]}" # "item 2"
```

---

**`IFS`** is the bash equivalent of the AppleScript `text item delimiters`.  It typically has a default value of `⎵\t\n` (where `⎵` indicates a space character).  More can be read about it in this article: [Bash IFS: its Definition, Viewing it and Modifying it](http://ahmed.amayem.com/bash-ifs-its-definition-viewing-it-and-modifying-it/)

Comment: Will accept this as the answer. I'm more familiar with Applescript, so when I can fall back to it I tend to do so, didn't realize it was this simple in bash though.